# Unable to retrieve external key (customer key) for triggered email

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, sql

I have a go to query retrieve details about my triggered email sends for analytical purposes. It has always worked.

However, for one triggered send in particular the query is returning 0 rows; despite the external key existing when I navigate to Interactions > Triggered Emails.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

```sql
SELECT
  s.SubscriberKey
, j.JOBID
, j.EmailID as EMAIL_ID
, ls.EmailAddress as EMAIL_ADDRESS
, j.EmailName as EMAIL_NAME
, j.EmailSubject as SUBJECT
, DATEADD(hh, 6, s.EventDate) AS SEND_DATE
, DATEADD(hh, 6, o.EventDate) AS FIRST_OPEN
, op.Opens AS TIMES_OPENED_CNT
, DATEADD(hh, 6, c.EventDate) AS FIRST_CLICK
, cl.Clicks AS TOTAL_CLICKS_CNT
, ISNULL(B.IsUnique, 0) as [Bounce Indicator]
, b.BounceCategory AS BOUNCE_CATEGORY
, ISNULL(U.IsUnique,0) as [Blocked Domain Indicator]
, DATEADD(hh, 6, u.EventDate) as [Blocked Domain Date]
FROM _Sent s
LEFT JOIN _Job j ON s.JobID = j.JobID
LEFT JOIN _Open o ON s.JobID = o.JobID AND s.ListID = o.ListID AND s.BatchID = o.BatchID AND s.SubscriberID = o.SubscriberID AND o.IsUnique = 1
LEFT JOIN _Click c ON s.JobID = c.JobID AND s.ListID = c.ListID AND s.BatchID = c.BatchID AND s.SubscriberID = c.SubscriberID AND c.IsUnique = 1
LEFT JOIN _Bounce b ON s.JobID = b.JobID AND s.ListID = b.ListID AND s.BatchID = b.BatchID AND s.SubscriberID = b.SubscriberID AND b.IsUnique = 1
LEFT JOIN _Unsubscribe u ON s.JobID = u.JobID AND s.ListID = u.ListID AND s.BatchID = u.BatchID AND s.SubscriberID = u.SubscriberID AND u.IsUnique = 1
LEFT JOIN (
  select
    jobid
  , ListID
  , BatchID
  , subscriberid
  , count(subscriberid) AS Clicks
  from _click
  group by 
    subscriberid
  , jobid
  , ListID
  , BatchID
) cl ON s.JobID = cl.JobID AND s.ListID = cl.ListID AND s.BatchID = cl.BatchID AND s.SubscriberID = cl.SubscriberID 
LEFT JOIN (
  select distinct
    jobid
  , ListID
  , BatchID
  , subscriberid
  , count(distinct url) AS URLs
  from _click
  group by 
    subscriberid
  , jobid
  , ListID
  , BatchID
) url ON s.JobID = url.JobID AND s.ListID = url.ListID AND s.BatchID = url.BatchID AND s.SubscriberID = url.SubscriberID
LEFT JOIN (
  select
    jobid
  , ListID
  , BatchID
  , subscriberid
  , count(subscriberid) AS Opens
  from _open
  group by subscriberid, jobid, ListID, BatchID
) op ON s.JobID = op.JobID AND s.ListID = op.ListID AND s.BatchID = op.BatchID AND s.SubscriberID = op.SubscriberID
LEFT JOIN ent._ListSubscribers ls ON s.SubscriberID = ls.SubscriberID
inner join [MY_JOURNEY_NAME] ju on s.SubscriberKey = ju.Email
where 
s.TriggeredSendCustomerKey in ('71156', '71157', '71493', '71494', '71952', '71953')
```

Comment: Please update your question to include details about the primary key of the target data extension.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Journey data views to select any sends for your Journey:

```sql
SELECT
  s.SubscriberKey
, j.JOBID
, j.EmailID as EMAIL_ID
, ls.EmailAddress as EMAIL_ADDRESS
, j.EmailName as EMAIL_NAME
, j.EmailSubject as SUBJECT
, DATEADD(hh, 6, s.EventDate) AS SEND_DATE
, DATEADD(hh, 6, o.EventDate) AS FIRST_OPEN
, op.Opens AS TIMES_OPENED_CNT
, DATEADD(hh, 6, c.EventDate) AS FIRST_CLICK
, cl.Clicks AS TOTAL_CLICKS_CNT
, ISNULL(B.IsUnique, 0) as [Bounce Indicator]
, b.BounceCategory AS BOUNCE_CATEGORY
, ISNULL(U.IsUnique,0) as [Blocked Domain Indicator]
, DATEADD(hh, 6, u.EventDate) as [Blocked Domain Date]
FROM _Sent s
LEFT JOIN _Job j ON s.JobID = j.JobID
LEFT JOIN _Open o ON s.JobID = o.JobID AND s.ListID = o.ListID AND s.BatchID = o.BatchID AND s.SubscriberID = o.SubscriberID AND o.IsUnique = 1
LEFT JOIN _Click c ON s.JobID = c.JobID AND s.ListID = c.ListID AND s.BatchID = c.BatchID AND s.SubscriberID = c.SubscriberID AND c.IsUnique = 1
LEFT JOIN _Bounce b ON s.JobID = b.JobID AND s.ListID = b.ListID AND s.BatchID = b.BatchID AND s.SubscriberID = b.SubscriberID AND b.IsUnique = 1
LEFT JOIN _Unsubscribe u ON s.JobID = u.JobID AND s.ListID = u.ListID AND s.BatchID = u.BatchID AND s.SubscriberID = u.SubscriberID AND u.IsUnique = 1
LEFT JOIN (
  select
    jobid
  , ListID
  , BatchID
  , subscriberid
  , count(subscriberid) AS Clicks
  from _click
  group by 
    subscriberid
  , jobid
  , ListID
  , BatchID
) cl ON s.JobID = cl.JobID AND s.ListID = cl.ListID AND s.BatchID = cl.BatchID AND s.SubscriberID = cl.SubscriberID 

LEFT JOIN (
  select distinct
    jobid
  , ListID
  , BatchID
  , subscriberid
  , count(distinct url) AS URLs
  from _click
  group by 
    subscriberid
  , jobid
  , ListID
  , BatchID
) url ON s.JobID = url.JobID AND s.ListID = url.ListID AND s.BatchID = url.BatchID AND s.SubscriberID = url.SubscriberID
LEFT JOIN (
  select
    jobid
  , ListID
  , BatchID
  , subscriberid
  , count(subscriberid) AS Opens
  from _open
  group by subscriberid, jobid, ListID, BatchID
) op ON s.JobID = op.JobID AND s.ListID = op.ListID AND s.BatchID = op.BatchID AND s.SubscriberID = op.SubscriberID
LEFT JOIN ent._ListSubscribers ls ON s.SubscriberID = ls.SubscriberID
inner join (

  select
    convert(varchar(36), ja0.VersionID) VersionID /* UniqueIdentifier datatype doesnt play nicely with JO-INs */
  , convert(varchar(36), ja0.ActivityID) ActivityID
  , ja0.ActivityName
  , ja0.ActivityExternalKey
  , ja0.JourneyActivityObjectID
  , ja0.ActivityType
  from _JourneyActivity ja0

) ja on ja.ActivityId = s.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID
inner join (

  select
    convert(varchar(36), j0.VersionID) VersionID
  , convert(varchar(36), j0.JourneyID) JourneyID
  , j0.JourneyName
  , j0.VersionNumber
  , j0.CreatedDate
  , j0.LastPublishedDate
  , j0.ModifiedDate
  , j0.JourneyStatus
  from _Journey j0

) jr on jr.versionid = ja.versionid
inner join [MY_JOURNEY_NAME] ju on s.SubscriberKey = ju.Email
where 
jr.journeyName = 'MY_JOURNEY_NAME'
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm seeing this error in query studio '.The correlation name 'j' is specified multiple times in a FROM clause'. However _job view is only being joined once

Comment: Fixed an alias issue in my query.  Query Studio will error on certain things in queries that Query Activities won't, so keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

The sends that are shown under `Interactions>Triggered Emails` are Triggered sends and not journey builder sends. So if you are trying to find the key for your journey builder sends, then the right external key would be under `Interactions>Journey Builder>Your journey name folder`.

Comment: You are correct, I actually meant Triggered Emails, not Journey. I have edited my question.

Comment: Can you paste in the structure of your MY_JOURNEY_NAME DE